# /root/bin/ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libtheoraenc.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: ffmpeg

my ffmpeg command gives error when I try to convert video format. I have installed ffmpeg manually as guided in this link https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CentosCompilationGuide. for above issue I have also checked https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34023/ffmpeg-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libtheoraenc-so-1 but not able to resolve my issue.

My command is : /root/bin/ffmpeg -i /home/pulsebrk/public_html/beta/user_uploads/6/1148a008470721f06c8dc71efa70622f99799e91.avi -acodec libvorbis -ac 2 -ab 96k -ar 44100 -b 345k -s x /home/pulsebrk/public_html/beta/user_uploads/6/1148a008470721f06c8dc71efa70622f99799e91.ogv and error is : /root/bin/ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libtheoraenc.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

libtheroa version is : 1.1.1 please anyone drive me for above issue.

Comment: Did you modify the guide at all or did you follow it verbatim?

Comment: I recompiled ffmpeg thrice and added ffmpeg lib path to ld.so.conf.d. and it resolved this issue. Thanks for your efforts.